# List of matrices: plot each element of matrix as a function of an index

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of matrices. I would like to plot each element of those matrices in function of another list.

However I am struggling to do it without using a loop.

How can I do it in the simplest way ?

Below a code explaining a little bit more what I want to do.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import *
import mpmath as mpmath
import pylab
import numpy
import time 
import math
from qutip.sparse import sp_eigs
import numpy, scipy.io
from random import *

randomMatrixList=[np.random.rand(2,2) for _ in range(10)]
index=np.arange(10)

# I want to plot on x axis: index, on y axis: randomMatrixList[ii][0] for ii
# corresponding to index[ii] for the "0" curve, then randomMatrixList[ii][1] for the first one, and so on
```

Comment: Please remove all unneccessary code. Most of the imports are not needed (e.g. `time`, `pylab`  etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do this completely without loops, but this way is somewhat compact. There is further cleverness to be done if you want, but the code below is a trade off in terms of explicitness and ease to understand.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

randomMatrixList = [np.random.rand(2, 2) for _ in range(10)]
index = np.arange(10)

stacked_matrices = np.array(randomMatrixList)
print(stacked_matrices.shape)
for k in range(stacked_matrices.shape[1]):
    for j in range(stacked_matrices.shape[2]):
        plt.plot(index, stacked_matrices[:, j, k], label=f"mat[{j},{k}]")

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("index")
plt.show()
```

The code produces the image below
[image: plot of the indices of the matrices]